# Load balancing and indexing in SolrCloud

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have some questions regarding SolrCloud:

1. If I send a request directly to a solr node, which belons to a solr cluster, does it delegate the query to the zookeeper ensemble to handle it?
2. I want to have a single url to send requests to SolrCloud. Is there a better way of achieving this, than setting up an external load balancer, which balances directly between individual solr nodes? If 1 isn't true, this approach seems like a bad idea. On top I feel like it would somewhat defeat the purpose of zookeeper ensemble.
3. There is an option to break up a collection in shards. If I do so, how exactly does SolrCloud decide which document goes to which shard? Is there a need and/or an option to configure this process?
4. What happens if I send a collection of documents directly to one of the solr nodes? Would the data set somehow distribute itself across the shards evenly? If so, how does it happen?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Zookeeper "just" keeps configuration data available for all nodes - i.e. the state of the cluster, etc. It does not get any queries "delegated" to it; it's just a way for Solr nodes and clients to know which collections are handled by which nodes in the cluster, and have that information be stored in resilient and available manner (i.e. dedicate the hard part out of managing a cluster to Zookeeper).
2. The best is to use a cloud aware Solr client - it will connect to any of the available Zookeeper nodes given in its configuration, retrieve the cluster state and connect directly to one the nodes that has the information it needs (i.e. the collection it needs to query). If you can't do that, you can either load balance with an external load balancer across all nodes in your cluster or let the client load balance if the client you use supports round robin, etc. - but having an external load balancer gives you other gains (such as being able to remove a node from load balancing for all clients at the same time, having dedicated http caching in front of th enodes, etc.) for a bit more administration.
3. It will use the unique id field to decide which node a given document should be routed to. You don't have to configure anything, but you can tell Solr to use a specific field or a specific prefix of a field, etc. as the route key. See [Document Routing](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/solrcloud-shards-indexing.html#document-routing). for specific information. It allows you to make sure that all documents that belong to a specific client/application is placed on the same node (which is important for some calculations and possible operations).
4. It gets routed to the correct node. Whether that is evenly depends on your routing key, but by default, it'll be about as even as you can get it.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer! To clarify 1: say, a cluster consists of two nodes n1, n2. n1 hosts the a replica of a shard s1_1 and n2 hosts a replica of the other shard s2_1. Say, n1 gets a direct request for a document, which belongs to s2_1. Then n1 should reroute the request to n2, right? And this happens because zookeeper stores the info about the location of s2_1. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: That sounds correct, yes. But remember that queries will go to all the shards in the collection (but it can know which nodes have each collection through Zookeeper), since you can't know who can answer a specific query otherwise. In general you don't have to spend much time about this for basic queries; this only becomes an issue if your documents are unevenly distributed (since scores are calculated per node, and there are also a few things like grouping/etc. which can be node dependent).